# SQLite DataType Field Size

Tags: sql, sqlite

Does SQLite require you to mention field size or are there fixed size for each DataType

```
ID INTEGER (10)

ID INTEGER
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

each datatype have fixed size. for more details check http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html

Comment: also SQLite is "typeless". This means that you can store any kind of data you want in any column of any table, regardless of the declared datatype of that column. One exception to the typelessness of SQLite is a column whose type is INTEGER PRIMARY KEY. source http://www.sqlite.org/datatypes.html

Answer (score 2):

SQLite will accept SQL dumps from most other databases, including INTEGER(10).

However, on import any column that has INT in its type will be considered INTEGER and will occupy 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, or 8 bytes [depending on actual value](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html).